# how to call a function from a different class in python pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, designer

Forgive me for overcomplicating this, thats just how it happened. so i have these two classes one's windowm and the other's modelm, i am trying to get it to re-start whenever newGame() is called so here are some snippets of code:

```
class windowm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(windowm, self).__init__()

        # a generic widget for the center of the window
        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

and the other class:

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        # setup is just starting a new game, so use that method
        self.newGame()

    def newGame(self):

        super(windowm, self).__init__()
```

yes i understand it is complicated and forgive me for that, that's just how the assignment is. So i understand that this has been answered before i just have this one annoying unique scenario. so as you can see in the second code snippet i am attempting to get it to jump back into the class "windowM" and into the function **init**(self) to re-start the game. please help and thank you!

Comment: Not sure that I understand your explanations, but `def newGame(self): windowm()` looks like all that you need. Also, please respect Pyhon's convention and capitalize your class names.

Comment: yeah sorry about that bit of a rush

Comment: so it says wondowm is not defined does it need something else? like do i need to add something to it? or perhaps one of the things like a from import etc.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a new instance of your other class and then use that to call the game function.

I think you'll want to change your game class though, so it's easier to start a new game from the other class.

```
class Model:
    def startNewGame(self):
        # setup is just starting a new game, so use that method
        self.newGame()

    def newGame(self):

        super(windowm, self).__init__()
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
class windowm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(windowm, self).__init__()

        # a generic widget for the center of the window
        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        # create an instance of the other class
        ng = Model()
        # start a new game
        ng.startNewGame()
```

Comment: so admitdly i am new to python, so do you know how i could do that in my instance??

Comment: i am confused by what you mean

Comment: I'm not sure where are you getting stuck? Is my example code returning some errors?

Comment: it doesnt know what "windowm" is

Comment: here's the error:     self.dothis = windowm(QMainWindow)
NameError: name 'windowm' is not defined